# Django change / override the delete link within a model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've got a model which i'm using the Django admin page to maintain. I've made a custom delete action as there were some extra steps to perform. This means I can select lists and delete through a custom view.

The problem I'm having is that if I click on a single instance of the model, where you would edit it, there is a delete button which is pointing to the Admins own delete url:

```
'/admin/myapp/mymodel/31/delete/'
```

How can I make this delete button point to my custom delete view, instead of the Admin default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the delete url in `submit_line.html` file. The file can be found in `/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/` folder of your django installation. Copy this file to your templates folder, so it will look like `/your_templates_folder/admin/submit_line.html`. The line which displays the delete button is

```
{% if show_delete_link %}
    <p class="deletelink-box">
        <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote %}" class="deletelink">
            {% trans "Delete" %}
        </a>
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

You can change the `href` url to the delete url of your choice. For example

```
{% if show_delete_link %}
    <p class="deletelink-box">
        <a href="/your_delete_link/{{ original.pk }}/" class="deletelink">
            {% trans "Deleted" %}
        </a>
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Almost got things working but have hit a difficult snag. It appears that since Django 1.4 I can't override this per App, which is a problem for me. To try to get around this, I added some extra_context to the change_view in the admin model and I wanted switch which delete was shown based on a variable. It seems that the request context is not making it to this template complete.  The variable is (annoyingly) available in some of the other admin templates called in the view. Any ideas how to work round this?

Comment: Ok, I've put in a {% block submit_buttons_bottom %} with the semi hard coded versions of buttons for my model. Its not pretty but it works fine. It seems that the context for this template is odd, as the variables it uses in the if statements are not available either

Answer (score 0):

Just make your view on the same url, and place it before `admin` in urlconf.